# Comparing two delegate objects are same instance

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused about comparing delegates. What I am going to do is to check two players to see if they are same. But when I try the code below I get a compiler error that says: "IPlayer is not convertible to MirrorDisposition". What is the ideal way to check for delegates in Swift?

Here is my code:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"


protocol IPlayer{
    var x:Int {get set}
}

protocol IMatch{
    var ballOwner:IPlayer? {get set}
}


class Player:IPlayer{
    var x:Int = 5
}

class Match{
    var ballOwner:IPlayer?
}


var firstPlayer:protocol<IPlayer> = Player()
var secondPlayer:protocol<IPlayer> = Player()

//here is the problem !
if firstPlayer == secondPlayer {
   println("equal")
}


// if i check with reflection there is no error. But is it correct way?
var a = reflect(firstPlayer)
var b = reflect(secondPlayer)

if a.objectIdentifier == b.objectIdentifier {
    println("equal no error")
}
```

Comment: Your title says "same instance"; your description says "they are the same". So which is it? Do you want to check that they point to the same object, or that the objects are equal?

Comment: i want to check if they are exaclty same object in memory :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `===` operator is used to check that two object references point to the same object. It is defined on two `AnyObject` operands.

But that won't work immediately, because `firstPlayer` and `secondPlayer` are not guaranteed to be objects. The `IPlayer` protocol can be conformed to by structs and enums too. To restrict it to objects, you have to declare it as `protocol IPlayer : class`.

p.s. `protocol<IPlayer>` can be written as just `IPlayer`.

```
protocol IPlayer : class {
  var x:Int {get set}
}

class Player : IPlayer {
  var x:Int = 5
}

var firstPlayer:IPlayer = Player()
var secondPlayer:IPlayer = Player()

if firstPlayer === secondPlayer {
  println("equal")
} else {
  println("not equal") // prints "not equal" as expected
}
```

Comment: protocol IPlayer : class {  
it gives error says "use of undeclared type 'Class' did you mean to use 'AnyClass'
If i change it as AnyClass then it gives another error "Inheritance from non-procol type 'AnyClass'"

Comment: Ok used NSObjectProtocol ... 

public protocol IPlayer:NSObjectProtocol{

It works now

Comment: @magden_suyu: No, it's `class` (lowercase "class", not "Class"). This is in Xcode 6 beta 5 by the way. In previous betas it would be `@class_protocol protocol IPlayer {`

Comment: i use Beta4 but i will keep it mind, NSObjectProtocol is fine for me because the objects that inheritance IPlayer are already NSObject

Answer (score 0):

The "IPlayer is not convertible to MirrorDisposition" error means that the compiler couldn't find the == operator for IPlayer objects.  To fix this, you could define it yourself, possibly like this:

```
func == (left: IPlayer, right: IPlayer) -> Bool {
    return left.x == right.x
}
```

Then, you can compare firstPlayer to secondPlayer without using reflect.

Comment: Actually i had tried this inside of Player scope but now i tried this out of scope and it seems there is no compiler error, Thanks